# Lucene TopDocs result not contains correct results when i set ResultSize

Tags: performance, lucene, full-text-search

```
int resultSize = 100;
TopDocs results = searcher.search(boolQuery, resultSize);

for (ScoreDoc docTemp : results.scoreDocs) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(docTemp.doc);                    
    addresses.add(helper.fillFields(_doc));
}
```

Here is my code and there are records more than `resultSize` but when I increase this number search takes longer but the documents which I am looking for can be in another part of same index. It's because of ordering as I understand the documents with same Score order by some field but that order is not returning me correct result .

Or can I increase my search performance? Faster search in 20m records
around 2GB File (RAMDir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should write the query that matches only relevant documents. Also you can pass more complex sort and provide secondary sorting field.

If there is a hard filter logic and Lucene indexes can be used only for pre-select documents you can inject non-index-based filtering in Lucene by implementing query or collector.

But it is a last resort. Proper indexes will be faster in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for suggest i will try to index other fields to get more filtered result.